# Delphi - change (ini) file but keep Checksum of crc16 equal

Tags: delphi, crc16

I am looking for a method to change an ini file but keep the checksum as it was before.
I know I can try to change some bytes until the result fits.
But I would like go an programmatical way.
Any ideas are very appreciated.

Background:
program checks the crc of the ini, if it does not fit, shows a messagebox and the user has to click "ok".
The program is launched from a batch and quits automatically when its done.
Very often, there is no user, so the programm can not do his job.
Autoit or similar can not be installed.

The crc check is obsolete in the meantime.
The Program is > 10 years old and we can not reach the developer and have no sources.

Comment: This is a pretty bizarre question. Do you care about the contents of the ini file? Surely that matters.

Comment: The content of the ini is save, as the whole environment is save. I just added some backgrundinfo to my original question

Comment: Sorry, that's making no real sense to me.

Comment: Wrong.  CRC is not one-way.  It is linear and easily invertible.

Comment: @Mark I don't know what you mean by invertible. I take that to mean that given a CRC value then you can recover the original byte stream. That's clearly not the case. So what does invertible mean?

Comment: To be very specific, it means that the linear transformation of, for example, a CRC-32 operation on selected subsets of 32 bits in the message can be inverted.  It is simply a 32x32 matrix multiplication over the Galois field, and the matrix can be inverted for those subsets to compute the input bits from the output CRC.  See my source code linked below for more details.  A randomly selected set of 32 bits has a 71% chance of resulting in an invertible matrix, but providing more bits to choose from rapidly improves the probability of finding 32 bits that are invertible.

Comment: For this reason, a CRC is the worst possible "digest algorithm", since it is very easy to construct a message with any desired CRC.  One-way digest algorithms are intended to be not invertible.

Comment: Oops. I meant a 71% chance of not being invertible. So a 29% of being invertible. But for each bit you add to potentially invert, the probability of not being invertible is cut approximately in half. So with 33 bits, it's 42%, for 34 bits it's 23%, and so on. If you provide ten more bits than the length of the CRC, the probability of finding a solution is 99.9%.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking.  Anyway, you can run [spoof](http://zlib.net/spoof.c.gz) yourself and see what it does.  A CRC is most definitely _not_ a [one-way function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function).  It is precisely the opposite of a one-way function, being a linear function.  It is the equivalent of the function f(x)=a x, with the inverse being f(-1)(y) = y / a.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is relatively easy to modify data to get a chosen CRC, since CRCs are linear functions.  My [spoof program](https://github.com/madler/spoof) will do this for you.  You choose what CRC you want and the bits in the message you will permit to be changed, and spoof will tell you which of those bits to invert.